# How to name a .aspx page with special characters in the name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Really simple problem, I wanted to create a .aspx page that has special characters in the URL/file name.  Here is a simple general example of what I am trying to do:

http://www.example.com/my-aspx-page-in-C%23.aspx

Note that in this case C%23 means "C#" once URL decoded.  I want to do this so that search engines will index the special characters in question.

OK - so how do I do this?  I don't think I can create an ASPX page with special characters in the actual file name.  And while it is probably possible to create a module of some kind that does this, I was hoping there might be a much simpler way to do this.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want it only for Search engine indexing then do not bother about url. Instead focus on Meta tags and title. For reference: https://seo-hacker.com/what-are-meta-tags-and-why-are-they-important/

Answer (score 0):

You can use friendly URLs in ASP.NET. Here's a tutorial:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Please bear in mind that % is considered an unsafe character in a URL. If you are unaware of what this is, please review the concept of unsafe and reserved characters in URLs:

https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/